# Microphone does not work on skype

Tags: sound, microphone, macbook-pro

I have a macbook pro Mid 2012 model (9,1) I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 and fairly new to linux. Everything works but the microphone I tried to do a test call on skype and it doesnt work.

I am attaching a screenshot on what I ab able to see in the drop down list when I go to micrphone settings.

Screen shot of my Skype Mic Settings - Tried a few of them but didnt work, just giving a heads up.

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/other_docs/Screenshot%20from%202013-11-14%2022%3A57%3A05.png?w=AACtOXh0M33o2U7IFRb70KhjF0PSYmqDtYQ-wr-WRReUow

Comment: The link is not working, maybe you set it private. With other non-proprietary programs (like Cheese) does it works?

Comment: So sorry tried adding the image to drop box to host it, turns out it doesnt allow me to share picture hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had this problem about 2 days ago... I fixed it in a very strange way, I'll just tell you what I did and good luck

go to sound settings (up right from the "speaker" icon) then go to "input" tab and play around a little. All I did was change the input device from the "record sound form" menu and then change it back to the mic.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your response :) Really appreciate it, Now when I try calling on skype I have a humming sound coming from the right hand side of my mac.  Althought If I turn off skype its still there but goes away on restart. I think its a hardware + skype conflict over ubuntu....

Comment: possibly! I've never had experience with such thing, sorry. in fact I want to say that I didn't notice that you were using a macbook from the first place :D ... about the problem, I had a quick look at this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1099618). I think it might help you fix the mic. thing but I don't know about the humming... just search and hopefully you can find something :D

Comment: one more thing... a good idea is that you edit this question and add to it the humming sound and all so that you can get better support from here :)